# PHP Query Not Understanding Integer

Tags: php, sql, integer

Here's my code:

```
    function display_name1($s){
        global $db;
        $query1 = 'SELECT Name From Drink where P_Key = $s';
        $r = $db->prepare($query1);
        $r->execute();
        $result = $r->fetchColumn();
        return $result;

        }
```

`$s` contains the result returned from the `P_Key`, an auto incremented column. I want to be able to give the query the `P_Key` and it will return whatever variable from that row I want. For some reason, this isn't working. It returns nothing. Now if I return `$s`, then it does display the numbers like it should, so the problem isn't with the `$s` variable itself. If I take the `$s` out of the query, and replace it with a number, then it returns the name of the drink just like it should, so the problem isn't with the database or the query. The problem seems to be that `$s` is being interpreted incorrectly.

I've tried converting it to an integer ahead of putting it into the query, no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using parameterized queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use double quotes.Single quote didn't interpret the variables.`"SELECT Name From Drink where P_Key = $s"`

Reference: [PHP String Parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Well done. That did it. I'll select it as the answer as soon as the site lets me.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
"SELECT Name From Drink where P_Key = ".$s.""
```

you can find difference using `echo $query1`